# Which is a better translation for the sentence "Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real." which will be used as a slogan?

Tags: translation

If I wanna translate the following sentence:

> Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's
>   all press "commit" button!

Which of the following is a better one?

> **让我们一起创造一个网站，让遥感和摄影测量成为现实。大家一起按commit按钮。**
>
> **让我们一起创造一个网站，让遥感和摄影测量成为现实。让我们按下"Commit!"按钮。**
>
> **让我们一起创造一个关于遥感和摄影测量的网站。大家一起按commit按钮。**
>
> **让我们一起创造一个关于遥感和摄影测量的网站。让我们按下"Commit!"按钮。**

Would you please consider the following facts in your answer.

1. About the meaning of the first sentence, it's not photogrammetry real. The explanation for meaning of the sentence is let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry come into existence. Or let's create a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry.
2. Also consider that I'm not searching for a word-by-word explanation.Just write down what you would say if you wanted to express the same idea naturally in Chinese?
3. [I'm trying to create an international community for remote sensing and potogrammetry experts in StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2).There are some remote sensing and photogrammetry groups or pages in facebook, Twitter,Google+, LinkedIn,etc. that have strictly expressed to just post in their local language. And since Chinese is the most widely spoken languages in the world (due to high population) and Chinese people are so active in scientific affairs, the number of such pages in facebook, etc. is high and so I cannot promote the idea in those pages in English and I should post in Chinese. So please consider the fact that the translation will be used to post on social networks for promotional goals. And I need a natural translation which requests the reader respectfully with kind of informality and intimacy (since I'm posting on social networks and I'm not writing a formal letter or paper to organizations) and also I need my request do not sound like begging.

Comment: English is my A language, and Chinese my B language (though it was technically first), and my first reflex is to say that the original English sentence seems pretty unidiomatic to me, and so I'm not sure what the "right" translation into Chinese would be.  Anything of the form "Let's make X real!" where X is as long and as technical as you have it ("a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry") just sounds awkward.  X is supposed to be something pithier than that.  (On a minor note, the second sentence isn't idiomatic, either, without a "the" after "press".) (cont'd)

Comment: I realize this sounds a little nitpicky, but issues of translation are already thorny, and adding in issues with the source language just exacerbate them.  I promise, though, that I will look at this question with the implied objective of making the Chinese result as natural as possible.  ETA: My personal preference is for the third rendering, but I don't feel confident enough in that for an actual answer.

Comment: @BrianTung Maybe you're right and it's absolutely probable. Since I'm not a native English speaker (I'm a native persian) and I got the idea of the sentence (in fact copied and just replaced the name of the proposal) months ago from someone who had promoted another proposal (i don't remember the name of proposal) which was in commitment in facebook. Maybe he/she wasn't a native, too.

Comment: I was an advertising director in Hong Kong, I know all about slogans, and the sentences you posted is not a slogan but a a body copy. Slogan is something catchy, short and to the point.

Comment: @Tang Ho Yes i agree with TangHo, I think what OP is referring to is more of a "call to action". Asking people to join in or commit on the cause. A slogan would be more like Mc Donald's "I'm loving it 我就愛"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer this one

> 让我们一起创造一个网站，让遥感和摄影测量成为现实。大家一起按commit按钮。

but slightly change to

> 我们一起来创造一个网站。一个可以让遥感和摄影测量成为现实的网站。大家一起按commit按钮。

This would suit better with your english version.

Answer (score 1):

This question was initially proposed in Chinese Meta [Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Chinese on topic here?](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/is-asking-to-translate-a-short-paragraph-from-english-to-chinese-on-topic-here)

Here's a few basic translations
攝影測量學 is the more technical term for photogrammetry. 攝影測量法 also works.
遙感探測 is for remote sensing, this can be shorted to 遙測 or 遙感 (casual/technical jargon) for those in the industry. However, for those who are unfamiliar or not used to the term, I would go for its more formal 遙感探測.

My personal localized translation for your slogan would be this:

In traditional Chinese, (use google translation to change from Traditional to Simplified)
開創新社團 Starting a new group/community (referring to a website)
歡迎對遙感探測及攝影測量法有興趣的人來加入 Welcoming those who are interested in remote sensing and photogrammetry to come join us

It's a "call to action" that doesn't sound so awkward. My personal opinion is asking people to "press commit" just sounds awkward. For English it sounds like your begging, while the Chinese translation, no one knows what commit is. Yet I understand the reason for mentioning the "commit" part because this is not a website yet.

For other SE users, feel free to give critics or opinions on my translation/localization